# HTML file doesn't use cached scripts, every time it's trying to contact server. How to stop this?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Network Tab screenshot]

In above image, index.html hits first, and in index.html I have given script tags for **CMTest.debug.js**
I want this HTML file to refer already loaded CMTest.debug.js, rather than contacting server for this file again and again.
If I'll be able to use cached script then my page can load in offline mode also.
Below is the index.html file.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp1</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="clickmobileweb/CustomScripts/CMTest.debug.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script>var jQuery = $.noConflict(true);</script>-->
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="clickmobileweb/CustomScripts/inline.bundle.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="clickmobileweb/CustomScripts/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="clickmobileweb/CustomScripts/styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="clickmobileweb/CustomScripts/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="clickmobileweb/CustomScripts/main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the HTML shown what the browser actually receives, or is there some server-side processing applied first to add the cache-busting `?_=xxx` parameters to each URL as shown in the Network tab screenshot?

Comment: There's no server side processing being done to add these random numbers.

Comment: So in the browser if you "view source" you don't see those `?_=xxx` in the source there? They appear sequential rather than random, but anyway, they must be coming from somewhere. jQuery will (depending on settings) do that for ajax requests, but I don't see how that would apply to `<script>` elements as shown.

Comment: Why is it saying that jQuery initiated the loading of those script files? Are you absolutely certain you're sharing all the applicable code?

Comment: Looks like you're loading `index.html` via AJAX which is loading from cache (see 304 - not modified). I wouldn't recommend fetching and inserting an entire document

Comment: Whatever you're using to load `index.html` should set the `cache` property to `true` for the jQuery AJAX config. By default, jQuery sets it to `false` for `script` types which adds the timestamp query parameter